# In Excel, how do I a call a user-defined function stored in another workbook without having to have the other workbook open?

Tags: excel, vba, shared-libraries, user-defined-functions

I have some VBA user-defined functions that I'd like to store in their own workbook so that they can be accessed by multiple other workbooks. I saw that an easy way to do it is to make the workbook with the commonly-used functions, then reference this common workbook using Tools > References (VBA window).

However, I now find that when I use that function in the calling workbook, it wants me to have the common-function workbook open. I don't want to do this, since that seems likely to create some confusion with my users.

What is best practice for sharing VBA functions between workbooks, without having to have the function "repository" open in Excel?

Comment: There's no way to do that without opening the workbook.

Comment: Save that shared workbook as an addin (xla/xlam).

Comment: @GSerg thank you. I've saved it as an xlam, and its functions are available in any workbook now. Of course this has generated another question ... How do I edit the macros in the xlam?  When I open it and go into VBE, there is nothing in the project browser.

Comment: There is something in the object browser. Just unfold it.

Answer (score -1):

the workbook should be open, but you can make it invisible
Dim commonWB as Workbook
Set commonWB = Workbooks.Open("path/file.name")
commonWB .Windows(1).Visible = False

Don't forget to close it when you leave the macro